# Why is Voltage Drop Across the Inductors of an LLCL Filter a Concern for Grid-Tied Inverters?

Tags: power-electronics, filter, power-grid, power-quality

I'm working with a single-phase grid-tied inverter that utilizes an LLCL filter to interface with the grid. I've come across design constraints that mention maintaining the voltage drop across the inductors (L1 and L2) to be less than 10% of the grid voltage in the figure below:

[image]

Given that the inverter output voltage is decided via its duty cycle, and considering there's a feedback control mechanism in place, I'm trying to understand why such a voltage drop across the inductors would be of concern.

The grid side is stiff, and from my perspective, the inverter can always adjust its output to cater to any voltage drop through its modulation index in the pwm scheme.

Can someone explain the rationale behind this voltage drop constraint in the context of grid-tied inverters with LLCL filters?

Source of figure:
Control and Filter Design of Single-Phase Grid-Connected Converters, Weimin Wu, Frede Blaabjerg, Henry Chung, Yuanbin He,Min Huang

Comment: Probably just because they're some BIG inductors if they're dropping significant mains frequency?